# The verb "take" can mean "remove" or

Tags: modal-verbs

1. The verb "take" **can** mean "remove" or it **can** mean "move" or it **can** mean "accept", *depending on context*.
2. The verb "take" **can** mean "remove" or it **can** mean "move" or it **can** mean "accept".

Qa) Can I say that "can" in sentence 1) relates to a ***particular*** use of the verb in question, whose context - when established - will quickly resolve the issue of interpretation?

Qb) Can I say that "can" in sentence 2) would be a ***general*** statement of possible meanings, not related to any specific context?

**Note**: I know the meaning of "can" is the same in 1) and 2). I'm just concerned about the two conclusions above.

Comment: You will have to provide some example sentences for clarity. But the first sentence is general statement. It's not talking about anything specific. Although that could be a meta observation.

Comment: With **interpretation a)** in the OP, which one do you think is correct? 1) *"The verb "take" **can** mean "remove" or it **can** mean "move" or it **can** mean "accept", depending on context."* OR 2) *"The verb "take" **could** mean "remove" or it **could** mean "move" or it **could** mean "accept", depending on context."* OR 3) **Both** 1) and 2).